# How can I check if I have permission to call chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab()?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

My extensions makes excessive use of chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab(), however if the user is browsing in pages that I don't have permissions on the call fails with the following error message in the console:

> Error during tabs.captureVisibleTab: Cannot access contents of url "chrome://settings/extensions#". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.

While this doesn't interfere with the normal flow of my extension, I was wondering if these is a way to check for permissions before calling chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab() to prevent my extension from seeming unprofessional

Answer (score 0):

Did you try handling the error with a try...catch statement? Something like this:

```
try {
      // If any error rises here
      chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab();
} catch(e) {
      // Supress the error and go here
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It seems that the error is not an exception.

Answer (score 0):

Just get extension's [manifest info](http://www.martinsikora.com/accessing-manifest-json-in-a-google-chrome-extension) and then:

```
for(var i = 0, permissions = {}; i < chrome.manifest.permissions.length; i++){
    // map array to object for later use
    permissions[chrome.manifest.permissions[i]] = true;
}

if(permissions.hasOwnProperty('tabs')){
    // capture
}
```

UPDATE:
Recently (dev channel) Chrome devs added new powerfull API - `chrome.permissions` ([docs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/dev/permissions.html)). So you can check if your extension have particular permission by:

```
chrome.permissions.contains({
  permissions: ['tabs'],
  origins: ['http://www.google.com/']
}, function(result) {
  if (result) {
    // The extension has the permissions.
  } else {
    // The extension doesn't have the permissions.
  }
});
```

Comment: This isn't enough of a check, since captureVisibleTab needs to have access to the URL, in addition to the `tabs` permission.

Comment: Of course - so you can grab the url from permission and check it manually (I do not have better idea). Btw. I hope you know that extensions can not access "chrome://" sites? So maybe checking url protocol would be enough?

Comment: I assumed that extensions can't access "chrome://" sites, I guess checking the protocol can be enough, I was just hoping for an easier solution (I'm using the "<all_urls>" permission, I don't want to start hardcoding HTTP, HTTPS, FTP, GOPHER, etc...)